# How to display listItem on emulator on recyclerview?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-emulator, adapter, listitem

what I am trying to do is show a custom card in a recyclerview.

I can see it on the design view on android studio, but no when the emulator runs.

I just need to display de listItem.

Is is posible? if so, any help or suggestion would be great, thanks.

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcvPoolVariables"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row_pool_objectives"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/containerVariableAndWeeks"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.xml

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/categoryview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:spanCount="2"
                tools:listitem="@layout/innercategorylist">

  </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

2.java file

```
CategoryModel[] myListData1 = new CategoryModel[]{
            new CategoryModel( R.drawable.kiwi,"kiwi"),
            new CategoryModel(R.drawable.watermelon,"watermelon" ),
            new CategoryModel(R.drawable.strawberry,"strawberry")

    };
innerCategoryAdapter = new InnerCategoryAdapter(myListData1, new InnerCategoryAdapter.HomeAdapterInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onRowClick(int searchText) {
            }
        });
```

3.Adapter class id define and assign and model class to variable getter setter set

Answer (score 0):

If the "preliminary version" is shown in the design tab, then there are no errors on the part of xml documents. It's in "regular" code part. I think the error lies in the output of elements on the device - either you do not pass data objects for output in recycler view, or there is an error in the processing of this data. Check the recycler view classes architecture and code of an adapter class. Also read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) guide, I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will look it up